# How to make involve all consumers for processing pending messages?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

We have 10 messages in `Activemq` and we started 2 consumers.But only first consumer consume and processing the messages. Second consumer not consuming the messages.

If I send one more message to `Queue` while first consumer processing time, second consumer consuming and processing that particular message(What we sent 1 message while first consumer processing time) only.After it's not consuming pending messges.

Finally What I understand, All pending messages are processing by first consumer not remaining consumers.

I want to make involve all consumers for processing of pending messages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking at is the [prefetch limit](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html) causing one consumer to hog a bunch of messages up front and thereby starving the other consumers.  You need to lower the consumer [prefetch](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html) limit so that the broker won't eagerly dispatch messages to the first connected consumer and allow other consumers to come online to help balance the load.

In your case a prefetch limit of one would allow all consumers to jump in and get some work.

Comment: What you suggested that's right.After setting `Prefetch value=1` it's working fine. I mention like `String url="tcp://localhost:61617?jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=1"`.is this correct way to do.